How does Verilog-A realize analog laplace domain transfer functions?
I am not able to understand how the functions like laplace_nd are implemented in verilog-A? (Laplace_nd takes the coefficients of the numerator and denominator of a s-domain transfer function and emulates the transfer function). My question has two parts:
First of all, it will need to decompose the transfer function into its constituents poles and zeros, how is it done? does it use an underlying polynomial solver?
Next, how does it implement those poles and zeros after they have been found? for example, if one of my denominator's constituent function is $$\frac{1}{s^2+ b_1 s+ b_0}$$
Here i assumed that it groups the complex roots together. But how will this be actually implemented? Will it further try to equate the coefficients to some standard topology like Sallen-key or some RLC circuit and try to deduce the values of circuit components from these values and then go and implement those circuits?
Thanks, any references for further reading will be much helpful!

I’m pretty sure it’s going to depend on the specific implementation. Verilog-A is just a language and the compilers will all be different. They all might use a similar strategyfor the Laplace functions, but no way to know without looking at all their source code and comparing them. You can probably start with looking at the ADMS source code, since it’s open source. https://github.com/Qucs/ADMS
